# Restructure nested JSON data by tags - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON file with post topics:

```
"topics": [
  {
    "id": "9551",
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
    "title": "title"
   },
   {
    "id": "9552",
    "tags": ["tag3"],
    "title": "title2"
   },
   {
    "id": "9553",
    "tags": ["tag1"],
    "title": "title3"
   }
]
```

I would like to sort these posts by tag, something like this:

```
 "tags" : {
     "tag1": [
         { "id": "9951",
           "title": "title"
          },
          {
          "id": "9553",
          "title": "title3"
          }
     ],
     "tag2": [
        {
        "id": "9551",
        "title": "title"
       }
      ]
    }
```

I'm not sure if the above is valid, but essentially I want a valid JSON output of the original data, only sorted by tag.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: _"I want..."_ - And we want you to show some (research) effort. So what have you tried so far? What problems occured?

Comment: A very rudimentary approach: I pushed all tags into a new array, and attempted to use find() in a for..each loop to filter the topics by tag and push them into a new array. It wasn't what I was looking for as it duplicated any entry with multiple tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the tags. Create an accumulator with each tag as a `key`. Inside reduce, loop through each `tags`. If a `tag` is already added, push the `{ id, title }` object to the array. Else, create a new array for that tag and then push it.

```js
const topics=[{"id":"9551","tags":["tag1","tag2"],"title":"title"},{"id":"9552","tags":["tag3"],"title":"title2"},{"id":"9553","tags":["tag1"],"title":"title3"}]

const group = topics.reduce((acc, { id, tags, title }) => {
  tags.forEach(t => {
    acc[t] = acc[t] || [];
    acc[t].push({ id, title })
  })
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log({ tags: group })
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version, which doesn't fix the output structure to just `{id, title}`, keeping what's there and removing only `tags` from each object might look like this:

```js
const byTag = (topics) => topics.reduce(
  (a, {tags = [], ...rest}) => tags.reduce(
    (a, tag) => ({...a, [tag] : [...(a[tag] || []), rest]}), 
    a
  ), {}
)

const topics= [{id: "9551", tags: ["tag1", "tag2"], title: "title"}, {id: "9552", tags: ["tag3"], title: "title2"}, {id: "9553", tags: ["tag1"], title: "title3"}];

log ( byTag (topics) )
console .log ( byTag (topics) )
```

```html
<script>  const log = (obj) => console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))  </script>
```

But if you're going to do this, it's barely a step further to make this generic, so that it works on any common property holding an array of strings:

```js
const groupByProp = (name) => (xs) => xs.reduce(
  (a, {[name]: n = [], ...rest}) => n.reduce(
    (a, x) => ({...a, [x] : [...(a[x] || []), rest]}), 
    a
  ), {}
)

const byTag = groupByProp ('tags')

const topics= [{id: "9551", tags: ["tag1", "tag2"], title: "title"}, {id: "9552", tags: ["tag3"], title: "title2"}, {id: "9553", tags: ["tag1"], title: "title3"}];

log ( byTag (topics) )
console .log ( byTag (topics) )
```

```html
<script>  const log = (obj) => console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))  </script>
```

The other advantage of this technique is that the items in the new data structure are not repeated when they have multiple tags.  Instead, each is a reference to the same object.  You can see what I'm talking about by comparing the two different logged outputs in each sample.  One of them shows the data structure as `JSON.stringify` might display it.  The second, the default for the StackOverflow script editor, notes shared references between objects.

Here we can see that `tags1` and `tags3` both contain a reference to the single output object with id 9551.  That may or may not be important to your code, but it's nice to know that this is done here.